# Как при активации вкладки присвоить классы блокам с одинаковым id?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день! Это вкладки. При нажатии на один блок `<div id="1" class="tabs">1</div>` блоку с `id1` присваивается класс `.tabs-selected`. А у нас блоки дублируются. Помогите, пожалуйста, сделать, чтобы при нажатии на один блок, класс присваивался сразу двум блокам, у которых одинаковые `id`. Спасибо за помощь!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tabs').bind('click', function() {
    $('.content').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).attr('id') + '-content').show();
    $('.tabs').removeClass('tabs-selected');
    $(this).addClass('tabs-selected');
  });

});
```

```css
.page {
  width: 500px;
}
.tabs {
  width: 124px;
  float: left;
  background: green;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.tabs-selected {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
.content {
  width: 500px;
  float: left;
  background: #ff0000;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page">
  <div id="1" class="tabs">1</div>
  <div id="2" class="tabs">2</div>
  <div id="3" class="tabs">3</div>
  <div id="4" class="tabs">4</div>

  <div id="1" class="tabs">1</div>
  <div id="2" class="tabs">2</div>
  <div id="3" class="tabs">3</div>
  <div id="4" class="tabs">4</div>

  <div id="1-content" class="content">Текст 1</div>
  <div id="2-content" class="content">Текст 2</div>
  <div id="3-content" class="content">Текст 3</div>
  <div id="4-content" class="content">Текст 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: используйте класс вместо id

Comment: два одинаковых id на одной страничке это плохая практика, используйте атрибуты. Для Jquery это - `attr(a,b)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нельзя дублировать идентификаторы. Лучше заменить их на атрибут `data-id`  работать через него. Вот набросал код:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tabs').on('click', function() {
        var $me = $(this);
        var id = $me.data("id");

        $('.content').hide();
        $('.content[data-id = ' + id + '-content]').show();

        $('.tabs.tabs-selected').removeClass('tabs-selected');
        $('.tabs[data-id=' + id + ']').addClass('tabs-selected');
    });
});
```

[Пример](https://jsfiddle.net/bat96w1j/).

Comment: проще уж тогда классы

Comment: Можно и классы. По мне - не проще и не сложнее

Comment: @LADYX: Да, это кроссбраузерно.

Answer (score 1):

#### Так делать не следует,

но с помощью селектора `[id="ваш_id"]` можно обратиться к элементам с одинаковыми ID.

Вот пример:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tabs').bind('click', function() {
    $('.content').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).attr('id') + '-content').show();
    $('.tabs').removeClass('tabs-selected');
    $('[id=' + $(this).attr('id') + ']').addClass('tabs-selected');
  });
});
```

```css
.page {
  width: 500px;
}
.tabs {
  width: 124px;
  float: left;
  background: green;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.tabs-selected {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
.content {
  width: 500px;
  float: left;
  background: #ff0000;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page">
  <div id="1" class="tabs">1</div>
  <div id="2" class="tabs">2</div>
  <div id="3" class="tabs">3</div>
  <div id="4" class="tabs">4</div>

  <div id="1" class="tabs">1</div>
  <div id="2" class="tabs">2</div>
  <div id="3" class="tabs">3</div>
  <div id="4" class="tabs">4</div>

  <div id="1-content" class="content">Текст 1</div>
  <div id="2-content" class="content">Текст 2</div>
  <div id="3-content" class="content">Текст 3</div>
  <div id="4-content" class="content">Текст 4</div>
</div>
```

Так делать не следует. Прислушайтесь к @Grundy и @ОлегДёгтев.

Comment: @LADYX Под всеми вы понимаете какие версии?

Comment: @LADYX, совместимость та же, что и в ответе Олега Дёгтева. Я оставил свой ответ для наглядности, как пример того, что даже в этом случае можно выбрать одинаковые элементы.